# How to do this curl request via php / laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I have a curl request that was given to me as part of an API documentation, and can't for the life of me get it to work via php (in Laravel).

The documentation says to do this...

```
wget -O- \
  --header 'x-user:x' \
  --header 'x-password:y' \
'http://example.com'
```

What I'm trying is this...

```
    $url = 'http://example.com';

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "test_user:test_password");

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    dd($info);
```

This is just echoing out Authentication Failed and then a bunch of info on my request, but not actual data.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First you are not passing the headers in your curl as specified in the API (as you said), secondly take a look at Guzzle HTTP client http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'x-user: something', 'x-password: something' ));